# Блоки в одну строчку без перехода

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно сделать так как на картинке. Я использую display-block, чтобы расположить все элементы в одну строчку, но начиная с 4 элемента, блок уходит на новую строку. Как быть?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML**

```
<div class="block_1">
    <div class="bedrooms"></div>
</div>
<div class="block_2">
    <div class="living-room"></div>
</div>
<div class="block_3">
    <div class="kitchen"></div>
</div>
<div class="block_4">
    <div class="cushioned-furniture"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bedrooms {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/bedrooms.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}

.living-room {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/living-room.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.kitchen {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/kitchen.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cushioned-furniture {
    height: 990px;
    background-image: url(../img/cushioned-furniture.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.block_1 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
}

.block_2 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 200px;
}

.block_3 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 410px;
}

.block_4 {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Как получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется лучше сделать через фотошоп

Comment: а текст через flexbox